# Maximum value of the quantity of energy transfered in a linear process

Tags: thermodynamics

In a linear process with an ideal gas, given by $p(V)=p_0-\alpha V$ ($p$ - pressure, $V$ - volume) in the $pV$ coordinates, the quantity of energy ($Q=ΔU+W$) transfered between point $A$ (with the highest temperature) and an arbitrary point $B$, both on the $p(V)$ graph, reaches its maximum when $B$ is the point of tangency of the graph with an adiabat of the gas. Why is this true?

[image]

Comment: Hi, a graph would be helpful for the understanding I guess.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that

Comment: is process reversible or not?  further what kind of energy transfered?

Comment: By energy I mean the heat which can be calculated using the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: because the pressure in the work done expression is the external pressure. you can say that is equal to the pressure in state diagram only if we are in equilibrium process and secondly the regular equations that we use are only applicable in equib

Comment: You are right, sorry. It must be a reversible process.